# Optimize a query on two big tables

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, optimization, query-performance

I have a very important query in my system that is taking too long to execute due to huge amount of data on tables. I'm a junior DBA and i need the best optimization I can get for this. Tables have approximate 80 million rows each.

Tables are:

`tb_pd`:

```
   Column            |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
---------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 pd_id               | integer | not null  | plain   |              | 
 st_id               | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 status_id           | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 next_execution_date | bigint  |           | plain   |              | 
 priority            | integer |           | plain   |              | 
 is_active           | integer |           | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "pk_pd" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pd_id)
    "idx_pd_order" btree (priority, next_execution_date)
    "idx_pd_where" btree (status_id, next_execution_date, is_active)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_st" FOREIGN KEY (st_id) REFERENCES tb_st(st_id)
```

`tb_st`:

```
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 st_id  | integer                | not null  | plain    |              | 
 st     | character varying(500) |           | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "pk_st" PRIMARY KEY, btree (st_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tb_pd" CONSTRAINT "fk_st" FOREIGN KEY (st_id) REFERENCES tb_st(st_id)
```

My query is:

```
select s.st                                               
from tb_pd p inner join
     tb_st s on p.st_id = s.st_id
where p.status_id = 1 and
      p.next_execution_date < 1401402110830 and
      p.is_active = 1
order by priority, next_execution_date
limit 20000;
```

With the indexes I have, the best I got was:

```
Limit  (cost=1.14..263388.65 rows=20000 width=45)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..456016201.43 rows=34627017 width=45)
         ->  Index Scan using idx_pd_order on tb_pd p  (cost=0.57..161388942.77 rows=34627017 width=16)
               Index Cond: (next_execution_date < 1401402110830::bigint)
               Filter: ((status_id = 1) AND (is_active = 1))
         ->  Index Scan using pk_st on tb_st s  (cost=0.57..8.50 rows=1 width=37)
               Index Cond: (st_id = p.st_id)
```

I cannot understand the explain very well but it's not using the `idx_pd_where` to filter the where clause. The `idx_pd_where` have all the columns used in where clause.

More info about data:
`status_id` is 95% = 1
`is_active` is 90% = 1
`next_execution_date` is in millis and varies a lot. The value compared is the moment of the execution (current time in millis)

Should I create separate indexes for each filtered column or use any different kind of indexes? Maybe some configuration on DBMS?

Comment: Version of Postgres?

Comment: How many distinct values are there for `priority`, `status_id` and `is_active`? The crucial column is `priority` and of all columns you forgot to give details for that one.

Comment: "SGDB"? ["DBMS" I suppose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980813/what-does-sgbd-mean)

Comment: Yes, it is a DBMS indeed, my bad, but it's from portuguese. The fact they use the same acronym in France is a coincidence. I'm a Brazilian, =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a tricky one. Your main condition is on `next_execution_date`, but the output is sorted by `priority` first. The conditions on `status_id` and `is_active` only play a minor part.

#### Better index

Your index `idx_pd_order` is not a big help, since filtering on non-leading columns of a multi-column index is not very efficient. Postgres is using it - still a lot better than a sequential scan. Details here:
[Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

`idx_pd_where` might be a better choice, but not a good one, either. The leading column `status_id` is not selective at all and just bloats the index. Same goes for the trailing column `is_active`. And `priority` is not in the index and has to be fetched from the table, making an index-only scan impossible.

I suggest this partial, multi-column index to start with. (*But keep reading!*)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pd_covering ON tb_pd (next_execution_date, priority, st_id)
WHERE  status_id = 1 AND is_active = 1
```

- Since we are only ever interested in rows with `status_id = 1`and `is_active = 1` exclude other rows from the index right away. Size *does* matter.
- The remaining (crucial) condition is on `next_execution_date`, which must come first in the index.
- `priority` and `st_id` are only appended for a possible [index-only scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) (Postgres **9.2+**). If that doesn't take, remove the columns from the index to make is smaller.

#### Special difficulty

We can now use `idx_pd_covering` to find qualifying rows quickly, unfortunately we have to look at ***all*** qualifying rows to collect the ones with highest `priority`. As the query plan reveals, Postgres estimates to process **34627017 rows**. Sorting 35M rows is going to **cost big**. That's the tricky part I mentioned at the start. To demonstrate what I am talking about, run `EXPLAIN` on your query *with and without* `priority` in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT s.st                                               
FROM   tb_pd p
JOIN   tb_st s USING (st_id)
WHERE  p.status_id = 1
AND    p.is_active = 1
AND    p.next_execution_date < 1401402110830
ORDER  BY priority, next_execution_date
LIMIT  20000;
```

That's your query, formatted only slightly simplified. You should see a *huge* difference.

### Solution

The solution depends on the number of distinct values for `priority`. For lack of information and for demo purposes I am going to assume only three. Priority **`1`**, **`2`** and **`3`**.

With a trivial number of distinct priority values, there is a **simple solution**. Create *three* partial indexes. *All of them together* are still smaller than your current indexes `idx_pd_order` or `idx_pd_where` (which you might not be needing any more).

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pd_covering_p1 ON tb_pd (next_execution_date, st_id)
WHERE  priority = 1 AND status_id = 1 AND is_active = 1;

CREATE INDEX idx_pd_covering_p2 ON tb_pd (next_execution_date, st_id)
WHERE  priority = 2 AND status_id = 1 AND is_active = 1;

CREATE INDEX idx_pd_covering_p3 ON tb_pd (next_execution_date, st_id)
WHERE  priority = 3 AND status_id = 1 AND is_active = 1;
```

Use this query:

```
SELECT s.st
FROM  (
   (
   SELECT st_id
   FROM   tb_pd
   WHERE  status_id = 1
   AND    is_active = 1
   AND    priority  = 1
   AND    next_execution_date < 1401402110830
   ORDER  BY next_execution_date
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT st_id
   FROM   tb_pd
   WHERE  status_id = 1
   AND    is_active = 1
   AND    priority  = 2
   AND    next_execution_date < 1401402110830
   ORDER  BY next_execution_date
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   ...
   AND    priority  = 3
   ...
   )
   LIMIT  20000
   ) p
JOIN   tb_st s USING (st_id);
```

This should be ***dynamite***.

- Strictly speaking, the final order is not guaranteed without an additional `ORDER BY` clause in the outer query. In the current implementation, the order from the inner query is preserved as long as the outer query is as simple as that. *To be sure*, you could join right away (which may be a bit slower):

```
)
SELECT s.st
FROM   tb_pd p
JOIN   tb_st s USING (st_id)
WHERE  p.status_id = 1
AND    p.is_active = 1
AND    p.priority  = 1
AND    p.next_execution_date < 1401402110830
ORDER  BY p.next_execution_date
)
UNION ALL
(
...
)
LIMIT  20000;
```

.. or carry along `priority` and `next_execution_date` to order once more in the outer query (to be absolutely sure), which is probably slower, yet.

- All parentheses are needed! [Related answer.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42852/postgres-9-2-select-multiple-specific-rows-in-one-query/42853#42853)
- This query just reads tuples from the top of above partial indexes, no sort-step needed at all. All rows are pre-sorted, efficient to boot.
- `UNION ALL` queries without a final `ORDER BY` can stop as soon the number of requested rows in the top-level `LIMIT` have been fetched. So if there are enough rows in the top priorities, subsequent legs of the `UNION ALL` query are never executed. This way, only the smaller partial indexes have to be touched.
- `JOIN` to `tb_st` later, should be more efficient.
- Again, the column `st_id` is only appended to the index in the hope for an index-only scan. If that works for you, the whole query does not even touch the table `tb_pd` at all.

### General solution for any number of distinct `priority` values

We have solved this before. There is a complete recipe to automate the creation of partial indexes and a function .. the works:
[Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500)

#### Optimize table

Since you are trying to optimize performance and your table is big, I suggest a slightly altered layout for your table `tb_pd`:

```
   Column            |  Type
---------------------+--------
 pd_id               | integer
 st_id               | integer
 next_execution_date | bigint
 priority            | integer  -- or smallint? -- or "char"?
 status_id           | smallint -- or "char"
 is_active           | boolean
```

This occupies 52 bytes per row on disk, while your current design needs 60 bytes. Indexes profit as well. Details:
[Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Of course, all the [basic advice for performance-optimization](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) applies as well.

[About `"char"`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html):

> The type `"char"` (note the quotes) is different from `char(1)` in that it
>   only uses one byte of storage. It is internally used in the system
>   catalogs as a simplistic enumeration type.

Comment: Nice one!  I'd add that one could give better names to these tables.  Changing the names could be rather painful, though.

Comment: With this 'non order' query using one index per priority, i could get my resultset in less than 1 second. Amazing.
Thank you very much for your time. Complete answers like this only motivates me to keep improving my knowledge so i can help others the same way.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be `tb_pd.status_id` and `tb_pd.is_active` have very low cardinality. For an efficient index range scane `tb_pd.next_execution_date` should then be the first column in the index. Inclusion of `st_id` might benefit the join. I would try an index on `tb_pd (next_execution_date, status_id, is_active, st_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
index(status_id, is_active,   -- in either order
      next_execution_date)    -- last, since it is a range
```

This is most likely to be efficient at filtering.  It will still need to re-sort and do the `LIMIT`.  There is no way to have an efficient index that handles both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`.