# Top N Results Ordered by Joined Table Column

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to optimize a fairly simple query that just gets a list of the top N users ordered by the number of followers they have. I am running into performance issues when I run the query a certain way, and I'm not sure I understand why the other way is better.

I have two tables, `user_account`, and `following`, with about 30,000 and 9,000 records, respectively.

I also created this materialized view `follower_count_mv` to hold cached follower counts for each user:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW follower_count_mv AS
SELECT followed_user_id AS user_id,  COUNT(*)::int AS follower_count FROM following
GROUP BY followed_user_id;
```

There are indexes on `user_account.user_id`, `follower_count_mv.user_id`, and `(follower_count_mv.user_id, follower_count_mv.follower_count)`.

Here is the first, slower query:

```
  SELECT ua.user_id, f.follower_count                                                                                                     
  FROM user_account ua
  LEFT OUTER JOIN follower_count_mv f ON (ua.user_id = f.user_id)
  ORDER BY f.follower_count DESC NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 3
```

and its explain analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=42756.30..42756.31 rows=3 width=54) (actual time=70.219..70.220 rows=3 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=42756.30..42831.88 rows=30234 width=54) (actual time=70.217..70.217 rows=3 loops=1)
     Sort Key: f.follower_count
     Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
     ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.69..42365.53 rows=30234 width=54) (actual time=0.010..65.185 rows=30234 loops=1)
           Merge Cond: ((ua.user_id)::text = (f.followed_user_id)::text)
           ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account ua  (cost=0.41..41893.22 rows=30234 width=50) (actual time=0.003..17.876 rows=30234 loops=1)
           ->  Index Only Scan using follower_count_mv_user_id_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv fr  (cost=0.28..316.52 rows=6416 width=41) (actual time=0.004..0.864 rows=6416 loops=1)
                 Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.233 ms
 Execution time: 70.240 ms
```

Here is the second, faster query:

```
  SELECT ua.user_id, f.follower_count                                                                                                     
  FROM user_account ua
  LEFT OUTER JOIN follower_count_mv f ON (ua.user_id = f.user_id)
  WHERE ua.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM follower_count_mv ORDER BY follower_count DESC limit 3)
```

and its explain analyze:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=400.19..425.80 rows=3 width=54) (actual time=2.689..2.785 rows=3 loops=1)
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=399.91..424.85 rows=3 width=50) (actual time=2.666..2.722 rows=3 loops=1)
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=399.49..399.52 rows=3 width=37) (actual time=2.627..2.627 rows=3 loops=1)
           Group Key: ("ANY_subquery".followed_user_id)::text
           ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=399.45..399.49 rows=3 width=37) (actual time=2.622..2.624 rows=3 loops=1)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=399.45..399.46 rows=3 width=41) (actual time=2.620..2.620 rows=3 loops=1)
                       ->  Sort  (cost=399.45..415.49 rows=6416 width=41) (actual time=2.620..2.620 rows=3 loops=1)
                             Sort Key: follower_count_mv.follower_count
                             Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                             ->  Index Only Scan using follower_count_mv_user_id_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv  (cost=0.28..316.52 rows=6416 width=41) (actual time=0.008..1.312 rows=6416 loops=1)
                                   Heap Fetches: 0
     ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account ua  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=1 loops=3)
           Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = ("ANY_subquery".followed_user_id)::text)
 ->  Index Only Scan using follower_count_mv_user_id_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv fr  (cost=0.28..0.31 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=3)
     Index Cond: (followed_user_id = (ua.user_id)::text)
     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.603 ms
 Execution time: 2.834 ms
```

Am I missing something? Is the query planner not smart enough to figure out it should query `follower_count_mv` for the top 3 results first, and then join on that? Is this correct Postgres behaviour? Is there a better way to optimize this query?

Comment: A nicely-asked question. It may help to include the table definitions, too.

Comment: Closely related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86038/sort-by-number-of-related-rows-in-referencing-table/86088#86088 I guess it's a duplicate, not enough time to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are not the same. The first one is required to perform a complete left join and then sort, in case the results of the left join render fewer records than the limit (in which case it would includes as many records from `user_account` as needed, in no particular order).

Your second query effectively cancels the left join and turns it into the equivalent of an inner join, which in this case is completely pointless because you will obtain the exact same result as:

```
SELECT user_id, follower_count                                                                                                     
FROM follower_count_mv
ORDER BY follower_count DESC
limit 3
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. If I need the outer join to include other user fields and users with 0 follower count, is there a better way to rewrite the first query?

Comment: Why outer join? If you're ordering by follower_count desc, then your main table is follower_count_mv, so you can use an inner join to users.