# Ignore duplicates while using join

Tags: postgresql, join, duplication

I'm trying to ignore duplicates between two providers in my tables while using join.

I'm using this query for now:

```
SELECT *
FROM A AS a1, A AS a2
WHERE a1.provider <> a2.provider AND a1.etype = a2.etype
```

Unfortunately, that query gives me duplicates (two rows of the same providers, in opposite sides).

I'm trying to ignore rows that appear twice in the opposite sides, for example:

```
etype    provider    etype    provider
hello    aaa         hello    bbb
hello    bbb         hello    aaa
```

This [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a23e5548e54b23195475085546fd2aeb) illustrates the desired output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the `<>` comparison by `<` or `>`. Otherwise the plain CROSS JOIN produce the full cartesian product with main diagonal excluded.

Now you get the next:

```
-- AB AC AD
BA -- BC BD
CA CB -- CD
DA DB DC --
```

instead of :

```
-- AB AC AD
-- -- BC BD
-- -- -- CD
-- -- -- --
```

So your query should look like that:

```
SELECT *
  FROM       A AS a1
  CROSS JOIN A AS a2  -- my strong advise to use JOIN instead of ',' for readability
 WHERE a1.provider < a2.provider -- here is the comparison I've mean
   AND a1.etype    = a2.etype
;
```

N.B.
Proper code formatting can improve the comprehension tremendously.

Comment: I second the preference for explicit `JOIN` syntax. But you do need a join clause to go with it. The current form of the query is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right, I always forget to switch from the `mysql` dialect.

Answer (score 2):

[What Kondybas explained about the appropriate operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221411/3684), but with legal syntax:

```
SELECT etype, a1.provider AS provider1, a2.provider AS provider2
FROM   A a1
JOIN   A a2 USING (etype)
WHERE  a1.provider < a2.provider;
```

[`[INNER] JOIN` requires a join condition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html), with either `ON` or `USING`.

To keep events with only a single provider in the result, use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`:

```
SELECT a1.etype, a1.provider AS provider1, a2.provider AS provider2
FROM   A a1
LEFT   JOIN A a2 ON a1.etype = a2.etype
                AND a1.provider < a2.provider;
```

The second condition has to move to the join condition as well in this case. See:

- [Sort by number of related rows in referencing table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86038/sort-by-number-of-related-rows-in-referencing-table/86088#86088)

Comment: May be the `INNER JOIN .. ON .. AND ..` would have more clear sense than `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Kondybas: Well, both are not doing the same. `INNER JOIN .. ON .. AND ..` is equivalent to my first query with `USING` but not with the 2nd query with `LEFT JOIN`.