# Handling INSERT race condition for generated unique column value

Tags: postgresql

I am generating a unique slug during creation of a record like so (based in this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86370/recursive-cte-to-find-unique-slug#answer-86404))

```sql
INSERT INTO ks.shares (
    , slugbase
    , slugindex
    , slug
    , userid
)
SELECT
    , Pslugbase
    , COALESCE((SELECT(max(slugindex) + 1)
            FROM  ks.shares s
            WHERE s.slugbase = Pslugbase), 0)
    , Pslugbase
        || COALESCE((SELECT '-'::text || (max(slugindex) + 1)::text
            FROM  ks.shares s
            WHERE s.slugbase = Pslugbase), '')
    , Puserid
RETURNING id, modified, slug INTO Vnewshare;
```

When testing under load this can raise a `unique_violation` as two concurrent threads both assess what it he current slug index before one inserts a record with the next available slug, leaving the second thread with a now invalid slug.

I attempted to solve the issue by LOOPING over the insert and catching and unique constraint violations:

```sql
LOOP
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ks.shares (
        , slugbase
        , slugindex
        , slug
        , userid
    )
    SELECT
        , Pslugbase
        , COALESCE((SELECT(max(slugindex) + 1)
                FROM  ks.shares s
                WHERE s.slugbase = Pslugbase), 0)
        , Pslugbase
            || COALESCE((SELECT '-'::text || (max(slugindex) + 1)::text
                FROM  ks.shares s
                WHERE s.slugbase = Pslugbase), '')
        , Puserid
    RETURNING id, modified, slug INTO Vnewshare;

    -- INSERT into two other tables

    RETURN json_build_object (
        'data',json_build_object (
            'id',lpad(Vnewshare.id::text,public.padding_constant(),'0'),
            'modified',Vnewshare.modified,
            'slug',Vnewshare.slug
        )
    );
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
        -- do nothing, and loop to try the INSERT again
END;
END LOOP;
```

(I took this pattern from an answer on implementing UPSERT but can't find it!)

However, when I deployed this function my DB instance got stuck twice running long queries that involved this function being called concurrently, so I seemed to have somehow replaced a race condition with a deadlock or an infinite loop

```sql
pid  |    duration     |                                      query                                      | state
------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
8187 | 01:47:35.477316 | select ks.post_share($1::text,$2::text,$3::bigint) | active
1188 | 01:57:56.955747 | select ks.post_share($1::text,$2::text,$3::bigint) | active
(2 rows)
```

- Is the approach to use a LOOP here the wrong way to go?
- Is there any way to understand what is causing the query to get stuck? It does not happen during load testing but appeared twice on production (which seems counter intuitive)
- Should I just return the conflict to the calling process and let the application handle retry?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `on conflict`?

Comment: Why you use INSERT .. VALUES instead of INSERT .. SELECT ? Additionally - you can lock the table during the query, and no conflicts...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Instead of the exception? So put the `ON CONFLICT` clause inside the loop and leave it empty?

Comment: You don't need a loop with the `on confict` option.

Comment: @Akina I don't have a specific reason. Is INSERT...SELECT better? Will locking the table have any adverse effect on performance under heavy load?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, that's the bit I don't understand then. What would I pt in the ON CONFLICT clause to call the same insert and then, if it conflicts again, call it again? Essentially I want it to keep trying until it finds a slug that is not used. (we have many people saving to this table with the same slug base)

Comment: *Is INSERT...SELECT better?* Of course - one query is better than 2 queries. *Will locking the table have any adverse effect on performance under heavy load?* Of course.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the isolation level, but if it's run under the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level, the SELECT part will never see the new values that other transactions inserted concurrently, so this code may be stuck in its loop forever.

> Should I just return the conflict to the calling process and let the
>   application handle retry?

Yes, it would make sense. The key is to retry in a different transaction, so it gets a fresh new snapshot, plus it releases whatever locks that may be blocking other transactions.

Another approach would be to not use `max(slugindex)+1`, but a sequence instead, **if the number part of the slug is globally unique**, not unique per suffix. The answer you linked is based on the premise that they want `abc-1` and `xyz-1` as opposed to `abc-1` and `xyz-2`, which is why a sequence is not an option. But it's not obvious that you share that requirement, looking at your SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @Akina and the answer from @Daniel I refactored my solution to avoid the infinite loop.

I am sure that Daniel's suggestion about [transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) is relevant and my attempt at retrying the index lookup was getting stuck (although it is not clear why this only happens some of the time and only under high load).

I could not think how to implement this using `ON CONFLICT` as it does not seem to have the concept of retrying the same `INSERT` with a different value for the conflicting column. It seems to support `UPDATE` on the conflicting row, not creation of a new record with adjusted values.

I took on Daniel's point about having a global index over a unique index for each conflict (this was based off how it was done in the legacy system) and after a quick check with the PO I used that to eliminate the race condition.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE ks.shares_slugindex_seq OWNED BY ks.shares.slug;
-- Set the sequence to the highest index we already have.
-- Although this would eventually happen anyway from the first loop!
select setval('ks.shares_slugindex_seq',  (SELECT max(slugindex) FROM ks.shares));


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ks.post_share(
    , Pslug        text
    , Puserid      bigint
)
RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE Vnewshare RECORD;
DECLARE Vslugidx int := 0;
DECLARE Vslugbase text := Pslug;
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN Pslug IS NULL THEN RAISE null_value_not_allowed USING MESSAGE = 'Pslug parameter is required.'; -- 22004
        WHEN Puserid IS NULL THEN RAISE null_value_not_allowed USING MESSAGE = 'Puserid parameter is required.'; -- 22004
    ELSE
        LOOP
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO ks.shares ( slugbase, slugindex, slug, userid)
                SELECT Vslugbase, Vslugidx, Pslug, Puserid
                RETURNING id, modified, slug INTO Vnewshare;
                -- Exit when no exception
                EXIT;
            EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
                -- add index to slug and loop to try the INSERT again
                Vslugidx = (SELECT nextval('ks.shares_slugindex_seq'));
                Pslug := (SELECT Pslug || '_' || Vslugidx::text);
            END;
        END LOOP;

    --- Do some inserts into other tables using Vnewshare
        RETURN json_build_object (
            -- Return the new record
        );
    END CASE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I choose to try the insert and catch the exception rather than checking to see if the proposed slug already exists for a record and append the index if it does. That is because doing a select and then insert would put me back in the same position of race condition that I was trying to solve.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am keeping the slugbase and index columns in case I get told to put it back in a months time!