# Reuse SELECT query by adding results in array?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql, cte

I have written a PostgreSQL function, which returns a specific order of products. Now I would like, not only to show, but to put the results of the first `SELECT` query to an array as well, so I can reuse the ID's inside another select query. I first tried to add an alias to the select query like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM products) as pr` and use `pr` inside the `NOT IN(pr)` statement of the second query, but that doesn't work ...

I will explain it more clearly with an example, this is a simplified version of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION featured_products(
    valid_to_in timestamp without time zone,
    taxonomy_id_in integer,
    product_limit_in integer)
  RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY

    (
    -- #1
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT "product"."supplier_id" FROM products AS "product"
    ) AS "featured"
    LIMIT 2
    )

    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT "product"."supplier_id" FROM products AS "product"
        ) AS "featured"
        WHERE id NOT IN (
            -- #2
            SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT "product"."supplier_id" FROM products AS "product"
            ) AS "featured"
            LIMIT 2
        )
    LIMIT product_limit_in;
  END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I deleted some joins and `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` statements, so the function is a bit more readable. And I added `#1` and `#2` inside the code above, so you know what I mean with select query 1 and 2.

As you can see the query #2 should return the same results as query #1. In reality these queries are much bigger. So you I just want to replace the second, identical query with just an array of ID's. Less code and probably faster.

I don't know how to add the IDs returned from the first query, to an array and put that in a `NOT IN(<id's>)` statement instead the second query.

Anyone who does know how to fix this?

Comment: How about a CTE (`WITH x as (...subquery...)`) at the upper level of the UNION query?

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Less code it is ;) But does it still execute the complete query 2 times if I use 2 times ```SELECT * FROM <name_of_CTE_WITH_query>```? Or does it save the results in some kind of cache? Cause it still takes half a second to execute the function

Comment: The CTE subquery should be executed only once, but more generally EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE should be used to know how the planner breaks down a query execution.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a textbook case for a **[CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html)**, like [@Daniel commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91780/postgresql-function-reuse-select-query-by-adding-results-in-array#comment164973_91780).
The example can be simplified some more. And you need to be aware of how `LIMIT` works in a `UNION` query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION featured_products(valid_to_in      timestamp
                                           , taxonomy_id_in   integer
                                           , product_limit_in integer)
  RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   WITH featured AS (SELECT supplier_id FROM products LIMIT 2)
   SELECT supplier_id
   FROM   featured

   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT p.supplier_id
   FROM   products p
   LEFT   JOIN featured f USING (supplier_id)
   WHERE  f.supplier_id IS NULL
   LIMIT  product_limit_in
   )  -- parens required - or not?
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

- `LIMIT` can only be applied once in a `UNION` (`ALL`) query, unless you enclose the leg of the query in parentheses. You may or may not want to add parentheses.

  - The way I have it, a maximum of `product_limit_in` rows are returned **in addition** to the "featured" rows from the CTE.
  - If you remove the parentheses you get a maximum of `product_limit_in` rows **total** - meaning that even "featured" products may be discarded.
    Related: [Optimize a query on two big tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66294/optimize-a-query-on-two-big-tables/66338#66338)
- Either way, don't **`ORDER BY`** the *outer* (combined) result before you `LIMIT`, if you can avoid it. Postgres can optimize the query very efficiently and just stop evaluating once enough rows have been returned (possibly fetching tuples from the top of a matching index). That would not be possible any more, which can make a **huge** difference in performance.
- Using `LEFT JOIN / NOT NULL` to exclude featured rows from the second SELECT, which is probably faster than `NOT IN` and does not carry "surprises" when dealing with NULL values or empty results.

  - [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)
- In Postgres (as opposed to some other RDBMS), you can refer to `p.supplier_id` and `f.supplier_id` after joining with `USING (supplier_id)`.

And yes, the CTE is only evaluated ***once***:

> A useful property of `WITH` queries is that they are evaluated **only once**
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling `WITH` queries.

**Bold** emphasis mine.