# "ERROR: column "a" does not exist" when referencing column alias

Tags: postgresql, subquery, syntax, column-alias

I am attempting to retrieve either a null or boolean value from a query. Here is my query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee
               where add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6') AS a,
       CASE WHEN a = false then null
            ELSE (SELECT exists (SELECT 1 FROM employee
                                 where add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6'
                                 and is_active = true
                                )
                 )
       END
```

Results in:

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "a" does not exist

Despite experimenting with multiple options, I am still unable to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: I’ve run into something similar earlier. You can use CTEs, even nested, and then refer to their output column names by referencing the CTE in the FROM list of your query. Nesting example: `WITH foo AS (SELECT a, b, a+b AS c FROM tbl), bar AS (SELECT a, b, c, c::BIGINT AS d, c - c::BIGINT AS e) SELECT d, e FROM bar;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases, like A, are not accessible in other columns due to the processing of the query.

You should make it:

```
CASE WHEN SELECT 1 FROM employe where add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6' = false THEN NULL etc..
```

Edit Peter: See Erwin's answer for a better answer!

Comment: Worked, thanks @Peter

Comment: How can some syntactic nonsense with barely an explanation accumulate many upvotes, I wonder?

Comment: Good question, I must say, I prefer your answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can only reference *input* column names in a `SELECT` list, not output column names (aliases). See:

- [Reference column alias in same SELECT list](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96556/reference-column-alias-in-same-select-list/96563#96563)

**If** `add_uuid` is defined `UNIQUE`, and `is_active` defined `NOT NULL`, it all burns down to just:

```
SELECT true AS a, is_active AS b
FROM   employee
WHERE  add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6';
```

This avoids scanning the table repeatedly, and also avoids evaluating a (possibly expensive) `count()`. It only retrieves a single row - ideally supported by an appropriate index on `(add_uuid)`.

**If** we can make no assumptions about your undisclosed table definition:

```
SELECT true AS a
     , COALESCE(is_active, false) AS b
FROM   employee
WHERE  add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6'
ORDER  BY NOT is_active
LIMIT  1;
```

`ORDER  BY NOT is_active` sorts a row with `true` first. About ordering by `boolean`:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/939860)

`COALESCE()` is only there to convert a possible `null` value to `false`.

In case there are no qualifying rows, the result is "no row", which should be clear enough. If you want `(false, null)` explicitly for this:

```
(
SELECT true AS a
     , COALESCE(is_active, false) AS b
FROM   employee
WHERE  add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6'
ORDER  BY NOT is_active
LIMIT  1
)
UNION ALL
SELECT false, null
ORDER  BY a DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

The outer `ORDER BY` is typically not needed, but to make sure. See:

- [Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/316818/3684)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the alias for one element of the `SELECT` list in another element. That would imply that those elements are processed in a certain order, which they aren't.

You could simplify your code with a subquery:

```
SELECT 0 < count(*) AS a,
       CASE WHEN 0 < count(*)
            THEN 0 < count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_active)
       END
FROM employee
WHERE add_uuid = '7e53fa47-ade3-4e94-8efd-b25f998b09c6';
```